# How can I return multiple string values using while loop+

Tags: c#, loops, iterator, return

This is what I want:
A method that is within a class that will return iteratively the values of a certain column. This values will the be added to a combobox when the method is invoked. Here is my attempt:

```
  public string FillCombo()
      {
            string connstring = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Arana;Integrated Security=True";
            string query = "Select * from categorias";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlDataReader read;
                conn.Open();
                read = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    string combodata = read.GetString(1);
                    return (combodata); 
                }
               return null;
        }
```

however, when this method is invoked, it only returns the first row into de combobox, not the other values.

Comment: How would you expect it to return multiple values? What would you expect the caller to see? It sounds like you should return a `List<string>` or something similar.

Comment: This will only ever return one result because you are returning the first item and exiting the function before the data reader gets a chance to read the next item. What's the result you are expecting - are you just attempting to fill a combobox with values from the database?

Comment: Instead if using `return` in your `while` loop which will `return` from the method, you could add each data value to a collection outside of your method.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `yield`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx

From the manual

```
public static System.Collections.IEnumerable Power(int number, int exponent)
{
    int result = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
    {
        result = result * number;
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

`yield` will send a collection of return results from inside a loop **after** the loop has completed.

You can close data connections using a try/finally block around the loop.

```
  public IEnumerable FillCombo()
  {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataReader read;
        conn.Open();
        read = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (read.Read())
            {
                yield return read.GetString(1);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            read.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

A cool and often overlooked feature of C#

Comment: @MikeChristensen most data connections support `IDispose` so wrapping the loop in a `using` statement will close the reader when the function exists.

Comment: I think if the data reader is *closed* before you materialize the enumeration, you're gonna get an exception.  I think you'd be better off returning a `List<String>` or `String[]`

Comment: @MikeChristensen what do you think of my edit? Haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: Yea, I'd have to test that out too.  If the `finally` block is executed *after* you iterate through the returned enumeration (which would be cool) then it should work!  I'm curious so I'll give it a shot when I have some free time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a List of string as an output. The following minor change to your code should help...

```
public List<string> FillCombo()
{
    List<string> comboList = new List<string>();
    string connstring = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Arana;Integrated Security=True";
    string query = "Select * from categorias";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    SqlDataReader read;
    conn.Open();
    read = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (read.Read())
    {
        string combodata = read.GetString(1);
        comboList.Add(combodata);
    }
    return comboList;
}
```

Good Luck!